# How do I successfully add %s to my a href link?

Tags: php, html, mysql, href

I've had a website for almost 10 years which lists my old radio shows from a MySQL database. Just recently the page stopped working, which I imagine is because most of the code has become outdated. I've tried updating the code, and everything works fine until I add the "%s" into the a href tag to pull up the actual audio file.

I need the link to say "http://www.hauntedamericaradio.com/audio/Episode%s.mp3"

Take out the %s and the page shows fine, put it back in and all the text on the page disappears.

Here's the PHP part of my page:

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "*******";
$password = "*******";
$database = "*******";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
  
 // Request the id of all the stories 
 $result = @mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM shows ORDER BY ID DESC"); 
 if (!$result) { 
   echo("<p>Error performing query: " . mysql_error() . "</p>"); 
   exit();
   
 } 
 // Display the newest story 
 while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH) ) { 
     printf("<tr><td align=justify valign=top><img src=images/%s border=0 bordercolor=#000000 
width=150 align=left hspace=5 vspace=5><p align=center><font color=#F9CF91 face=verdana 
size=+1>Episode %s - %s</font></p>",$row["Photo"], $row["Episode"], $row["Headline"]);
    printf("<p align=justify><font color=#F9CF91 face=verdana 
size=-1>%s</font>",$row["Description"]);
    printf("<p align=center><font color=#F9CF91 face=verdana size=+1><a 
href=http://www.hauntedamericaradio.com/audio/Episode.mp3>Click To Listen</a></font></p></TD> 
</TR><TR><TD><HR width=99% color=black></TD></TR>", $row["Link"]);

} 

?>
```

This is what the page looks like when it's working (minus the broken audio links):

```
http://www.hauntedamericaradio.com/btrarchives.php
```

Here's what it looks like with the %s in the link:

```
http://www.hauntedamericaradio.com/btrarchives1.php
```

Thanks guys for any help you can give!

Comment: Tried to visit your link http://www.hauntedamericaradio.com/audio/Episode%s.mp3 it is not working

Comment: Blank page usually means there is a server error, try enable PHP error report on your page.

Comment: Yes I know, that is the problem.

Comment: Not sure how to add but I'll research

Comment: `%` is a reserved character in the URL spec used for percent-encoding, so it could be that is throwing something off. Though traveling up one directory into the [`/audio`](http://www.hauntedamericaradio.com/audio/) directory shows that the file `Episode%s.mp3` does not exist.

Comment: I enabled error reporting and got this: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in /home4/ncognito66/hauntedamerica/btrarchives1.php:32 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home4/ncognito66/hauntedamerica/btrarchives1.php on line 32"

Comment: %s is the variable pulling the info from the database. It works fine filling in the Episode name, Photo, Headline, and Description, but it fails in the mp3 link. The %s is supposed to be replaced by the appropriate episode number. (i.e. episode1.mp3, episode2.mp3, etc.)

Comment: I apologize for missing the `printf` function call. Given that the error is related to a `query()` method call on null. I suspect there's an issue with your DB handling, either the connection isn't established returning a null connection, or you're mixing OOP MySQLi and procedural MySQLi. See if the examples for [fetch-array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) can help you in anyway.

Comment: Kim, thank you for the comments. Thank you everyone else as well. I solved my problem when I finally just sat and thought about it. The most recent error I was getting was "too few arguments" for my query, so I asked myself what it was looking for. It was looking for the "%s", so if it was too few I checked my code for a simple, standalone "%"....and there it was! My code included, "HR width=99%", once I removed the "%" everything worked fine! Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you have to encode those characters in the URL

for `%` we use `%25` ... space for instance is `%20`

It is based on the HEX code from the ascii table

So your URL will be http://www.hauntedamericaradio.com/audio/Episode%25s.mp3

you can find it all here https://ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm